# How to get a total for multiple SUM statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have two columns that I need to SUM based on WHERE statements, each column then returns a total and I also need to add up the resulting SUM values to give a final total.

I can get the individual SUM value for each column using UNION ALL but cannot then add them up for a final total.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(NILH1), 0) AS SUM
FROM [IG_300M19].[dbo].[Stn14_RFT]
WHERE NILH1 <= 25
  AND DateStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-17 08:00' AND '2019-04-17 08:00'

UNION ALL

SELECT ISNULL(SUM(NILH2), 0) AS SUM
FROM [IG_300M19].[dbo].[Stn14_RFT]
WHERE NILH2 <= 25
  AND DateStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-17 08:00' AND '2019-04-17 08:00';
```

The above returns two values one a total for NILH1 and one for NILH2, now I need to add these together to give the final total.

Comment: It's pretty simple, you can just wrap the inner query in an outer `select sum(sum) from (<inner query here>) as InnerQuery` - though there are other ways to get the results you want without doing a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both queries have the same `WHERE` is this not as simple as:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN NILH1 <= 25 THEN NILH1 END, 0)) AS NILH1SUM,
       SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN NILH2 <= 25 THEN NILH2 END, 0)) AS NILH2SUM,
       SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN NILH1 <= 25 THEN NILH1 END, 0) + ISNULL(CASE WHEN NILH2 <= 25 THEN NILH2 END, 0)) AS TotalSum
FROM [IG_300M19].[dbo].[Stn14_RFT]
WHERE DateStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-17 08:00' AND '2019-04-17 08:00';
```

To perform a `SUM` on a column you don't need to have multiple `SELECT` statements, you can aggregate on multiple columns in the same statement, and can use those expressions to make further calculations.

Comment: The `where` clauses reference different columns: `NILH1` and `NILH2`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that @HABO, nice spot.

Comment: And fixed @HABO

Comment: Brilliant thanks, works a charm and I can roll it out across a larger dataset

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation; move the condition from `WHERE` clause to `SUM` function:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN NILH1 <= 25 THEN NILH1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN NILH2 <= 25 THEN NILH2 ELSE 0 END
)
FROM [IG_300M19].[dbo].[Stn14_RFT]
WHERE DateStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-17 08:00' AND '2019-04-17 08:00'
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly returning the total and can be expanded for multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

For such a example data:

```
select * into #tab from (
    select 1 as NILH1,  2 as NILH2, cast('2019-03-17 18:00' as datetime) as DateStamp
    union all select 2, 3, cast('2019-03-17 18:00' as datetime)
    union all select 3, 4, cast('2019-03-17 18:00' as datetime)
    union all select 4, 5, cast('2019-06-17 18:00' as datetime)
    union all select 28, 29, cast('2019-03-17 18:00' as datetime)
) data

select * from #tab

--  NILH1   NILH2  DateStamp
--  --------------------------------------
--  1       2      2019-03-17 18:00:00.000
--  2       3      2019-03-17 18:00:00.000
--  3       44     2019-03-17 18:00:00.000  
--  4       5      2019-06-17 18:00:00.000  <-- invalid timestamp
--  28      6      2019-03-17 18:00:00.000
```

you can use CTE:

```
;with SUMS as
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN NILH1 <= 25 THEN NILH1 ELSE 0 END) as NILH1SUM,
        SUM(CASE WHEN NILH2 <= 25 THEN NILH2 ELSE 0 END) as NILH2SUM
    FROM #tab
    WHERE DateStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-17 08:00' AND '2019-04-17 08:00'
)
select
    NILH1SUM as NILH1SUM,
    NILH2SUM as NILH2SUM,
    NILH1SUM + NILH2SUM as TOTAL
from
    SUMS

-- NILH1SUM NILH2SUM TOTAL
-- -----------------------
-- 6        11        17
```